# Remove 'filter data...' row from Dash datatable without disabling filterieng

Tags: python, plotly-dash

i am attempting to filter through a datatable in Python Dash, like this datatable:

```
dash_table.DataTable(
            id='datatable-paging-filtering',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
            data=df.to_dict("records"),
            page_size=PAGE_SIZE,
            page_current=0,
            filter_action='native',
            sort_action='native',
            sort_mode='multi',
            column_selectable="single",
            row_selectable="multi",
            selected_columns=[],
            selected_rows=[],
            style_header={
                'color': 'seagreen',
                'backgroundColor' : 'rgb(255, 255, 255s)',
                'fontWeight' : 'bold'
            },
            style_data_conditional=[{
                'if': {'row_index': 'even'},
                'backgroundColor': 'rgb(235, 235, 235)'
            }],
            style_table={'overflow': 'scroll'}
        ),
```

I am using a input field to determine the search query instead of the built in datatable filter data row. So therefore, wheen displaying the datatable, i want the row that says 'filter data...' on all column positions to be removed, without the use of actions like a button, but before it shown to the viewer of the app. That way, that column will never be shown, and i will still be able to fiilter through without disablign filtering.

I have tried multiple things to fix it. I tried changing filter action to custom, however that did nothing, or i do not know how to use custom to remove it. I also tried dissablign the filter action entirely, which worked, but also made my other filtering method not working.

The expected result is to have a datatable, wwith that row completely removed, or not visible to the viewer of the appp, but still enable the datatable to have filtering functionality outside of that row.

Sorry for poor formulation.